# Método static não reconhece campos no aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Esse método precisa ser static

```
[WebMethod]
        public void ValidaSenhaAntiga(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long CPF = Helper.DFrmtCPF(cpf.Value);
            string senhaAtual = SenhaAtual.Value;
            bool senhaAt = ws_usuario.getSenhaAtual(senhaAtual);
            if (!senhaAt)
                lblMsg1.Text = Helper.ExibirMsgAlerta("A senha não confere.");
        }
```

O problema é que quando eu coloco static ele não reconhece `SenhaAtual.Value` e nem `cpf.Value`, pois esses campos vêm de uma página `aspx`. Eu estou usando o `PageMethods` e pela pesquisa que fiz na internet ele só trabalha com `public static`. O que eu estou fazendo é por javascript executar um método no code behind, para validar uma senha, ou seja, no campo SenhaAtual o usuário digita a senha atual e essa função busca no BD e compara com que o usuário digitou e retorna true ou false. Como eu faço para usar o `PageMethods`, com método `public static` e campos do `aspx`? No js tenho isso, mas preciso melhorar:

```
function ValidaSenhaAtual() {
    PageMethods.ValidaSenhaAntiga(true, false);
}
```

Essa edição, eu tentei fazer de outra forma.Criei essa função js

```
function ValidaSenhaAtual() {
    $.get('minha_pagina.aspx/ValidaSenhaAntiga', {
        NovaSenha: $('#conteudo_SenhaAtual').val()
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.senhaAt === true)
            alert('ok');
    });
}
```

Para chamar esse método no code behind

```
[WebMethod]
        public void ValidaSenhaAntiga(string NovaSenha)
        {
            //long CPF = Helper.DFrmtCPF(cpf.Value);
            //string senhaAtual = SenhaAtual.Value;
            bool senhaAt = ws_usuario.getSenhaAtual(NovaSenha);
            //if (!senhaAt)
               // lblMsg1.Text = Helper.ExibirMsgAlerta("A senha não confere.");
        }
```

Essa abordagem não funciona também. Acho que isso `$.get('minha_pagina.aspx/ValidaSenhaAntiga` tá errado. Quando chega nessa linha, ele pula a função.

Comment: Para melhor esclarecimento, poderia, por gentileza, colocar o erro apresentado?

Comment: @HyagoSantos, em realidade o erro é em design time, ou seja, nem compila. Os campos referentes a página já ficam sublinhados em vermelhos.

Comment: E por que você não envia esses campos por parâmetros também?

Comment: *"eu coloco static ele não reconhece SenhaAtual.Value"* porque `SenhaAtual` deve ser um membro da classe e não é static. Se um método for static, todos os membros da classe que for acessar tbm devem ser static, ou ia ter de criar dentro do método uma instancia da própria classe

Comment: @RicardoPontual acredito que porque no .aspx `SenhaAtual` deve ser o campo do formulário dele, neste caso não é possível utiliza-lo como `static`.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling si nesse caso não seria possível ser static, eu comentei isso pq na pergunta não mostra de onde vem o `Senha` atual, mas o problema é esse que comentei, o fato dele não ser static